# ESXi on VMware Workstation and VLANs

Tags: networking, virtualization, vmware, hyper-v, vlan

I am configuring VLAN tagging on a nested ESXi hosted on VMware Workstation installed on a Windows 11 PC. Overly complicated, I know, but I need ESXi and don't want to sacrifice having a personal PC.

Here's a primitive network diagram:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HR6YY.png

All relevant ports on a switch are trunk. Port 19 is connected to a firewall interface tagged VLAN2.

For VLAN tagging on a Windows host, I am using Hyper-V virtual switches. Here is tagged VLAN2 switch associated with parent virtual switch "External" which is bridged to a physical adapter on Windows 11 PC.

```
Add-VMNetworkAdapter -ManagementOS -Name "VLAN2" -SwitchName "External" -Passthru | Set-VMNetworkAdapterVlan -Access -VlanId 2
```

```
Get-VMNetworkAdapter -All

Name                                           IsManagementOs VMName          SwitchName     MacAddress   Status IPAddr
                                                                                                                 esses
----                                           -------------- ------          ----------     ----------   ------ ------
Host Vnic C08CB7B8-9B3C-408E-8E30-5E16A3AEB444 True                           Default Switch 00155DC008FB {Ok}
External                                       True                           External       2CF05D95DC4F {Ok}
VLAN3                                          True                           External       00155D006402 {Ok}
VLAN2                                          True                           External       00155D006400 {Ok}
```

In Workstation, two network adapters are assigned to ESXi machine - above mentioned External Hyper-V switch (ESXi vmnic0) and VLAN2 (vmnic1).

vmnic0 is connected to a vSwitch where domain controller is placed, vmnic1 is connected to a second vSwitch, tagged VLAN2 and I have test windows-01 machine there.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHYc4.png

Main switch containing domain controller, untagged:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SB6V.png

End goal is to have endpoint-01 (VLAN2) machine on ESXi get IP address from DHCP, but obviously needs to go over physical network to reach domain controller.

This for some reason doesn't work, and probably due to ESXi configuration or just ESXi interface/vSwitch behavior.

I have tested this with a separate Windows 10 endpoint (endpoint-01-hep) on Workstation. That works, it's in VLAN2, gets IP address in 10.0.2.X/24 subnet as it should. So the Rube Goldberg machine with Hyper-V switches works.

Any idea where am going wrong?